# how to make bearer token generated dynamically to work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[image]

[image]
I have no problem when i try to create event in other people's calender when i get bearer token copied from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and place it in postman, but i want to make this dynamic since bearer token expires. I tried generating bearer token dynamic and use it, but im getting below error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-26T17:23:39",
            "request-id": "aeeb1036-b9aa-4f6a-9265-936c94120e66",
            "client-request-id": "aeeb1036-b9aa-4f6a-9265-936c94120e66"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because graph explorer uses the delegate permission model, meaning it runs in the context of a user and you can leverage the /me endpoint there.

But when using Oauth 2.0 client credential flow, the token will have application claims(meaning running in the context of an application). Thus you cannot use /me endpoint. (try /user instead of /me)

Client -------JWT Token ---Application

You can try obtaining token using **Oauth 2.0 Authorization code flow** instead and it should solve your issue.

Client ---JWT Token --User---Application

Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#authorization-request) to leverage this flow.

Comment: Thankyou Shweta, Really appreciate it. on the same line, could you please help me this. i was able to create calendar event, but not able to read the response..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074524/could-not-read-response-in-microsoft-graph-api-getting-406-error