# Could not read response in microsoft graph api, getting 406 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create calendar event, and my post call is successful, but I dont get the reponse, instead im getting this error, i tried changing my 'Content-Type' to every single suggestion here, but i couldnt get the response. Instead I get the error code 406 with below message. Can anyone please help.

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorNotAcceptable","message":"A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the acceptable MIME types for the request. The supported type(s) 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatib...' do not match any of the acceptable MIME types 'text/*'."}}
```

below is my code:

```
require(['N/https'],
function(https){
       
    function getAuthToken(){
        return "<mytokengoeshere>"}
    
    function getbody(){
var reqBody = {
    "subject": "sub test",
    "body": {
       
        "content": "test?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2021-09-02T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2021-09-02T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "mick@gmail.com",
                "name": "mick"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ]
};
return JSON.stringify(reqBody);
    
    }
function process(){

var headers = {};
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false';
headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + getAuthToken();
var responseStr = https.post({
    url : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>/events',
    body : getbody(),
     
    headers : headers
});
log.debug('test',JSON.parse(responseStr.body)); //im getting the error message mentioned at the start of this post.
var gg=0
}
process();
});
```

Comment: its working when i included in header --> headers['Accept'] ='*/*';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I included in header:

```
--> headers['Accept'] ='/';
```